# How can I do this when an Accordion open and the other shuts off?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, accordion

I'm trying to make an Accordion for one of my projects. My Accordion is working. Now every clicking on the Accordion titles shows content and all the Accordions are open. But when I open an Accordion, then another Accordion will be closed.

Here is my Project: https://siddiknmh.github.io/jquery-accordion

And my jquery code is:

```
$('.acc_title').click(function(){

    var accdata = $(this).attr('acc-data');
    var selector = '.'+accdata;
    $(selector).slideToggle();

});
```

I hope this does not require more code writing but I can not find the idea.

Comment: `$(this).slideToggle()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do this by getting the `.parent().siblings()` of `this`:**

**Step 1**. get `.parent().siblings()` of `this` and iterate for each

**Step 2**. check if content div is visible `$(this).find('.acc_content').is( ":visible")`

**Step 3**. do the `slideToggle()` on that div.

**This is the running snippet:**

```js
 

   $(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('.acc_title').click(function(){     
  var accdata = $(this).attr('acc-data');
  var selector = '.'+accdata;
  $(selector).slideToggle();
  $(this).parent().siblings().each(function() {
                    if($(this).find('.acc_content').is( ":visible")){
                       $(this).find('.acc_content').slideToggle();
                    }
        });
     
 });
   });
```

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
.acc_warap{
 width:600px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.single_acc{
 margin-bottom:20px;
 background:#F0F4F8;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.acc_title{
 background:#BCBCBC;
 padding:10px 20px;
 border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.acc_content{
 padding:20px;
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="acc_warap">
 
  <div class="single_acc">
   <div class="acc_title" acc-data="no1">
    <h4>This is accordion title</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="acc_content no1">
    <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.</p>
   </div>
  </div><!-- End single accordion-->
  
  <div class="single_acc">
   <div class="acc_title" acc-data="no2">
    <h4>This is accordion title</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="acc_content no2">
    <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.</p>
   </div>
  </div><!-- End single accordion-->
  
  <div class="single_acc">
   <div class="acc_title" acc-data="no3">
    <h4>This is accordion title</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="acc_content no3">
    <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.</p>
   </div>
  </div><!-- End single accordion-->
  
  <div class="single_acc">
   <div class="acc_title" acc-data="no4">
    <h4>This is accordion title</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="acc_content no4">
    <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.</p>
   </div>
  </div><!-- End single accordion-->
  
 </div>
```